# Best Practice for Structuring Firebase when applying security rules?

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security

I was wondering what the best practice was for separating different types of information within a child, in particular for purposes of applying Firebase Security Rules. My case involves keeping track of a user’s id (their e-mail) within the child, so I can associate it with appropriate sections of our DB and restrict access as needed using Firebase Security Rules, like so:

[image]

In the case above, during certain processes our application needs to enumerate the children of the key ending in “xJEm”. However, enumerating accurately requires the application to ignore the owner child, in order for the information to be parsed correctly. This pattern repeats throughout other children in the Firebase, and requires specific “ignore upkeep” in our code. So my question is whether it’s better to:

1. keep the information mixed like it is above and have conditions
   checking for the owner child in my code
2. separate all the information
   into its own “data” child, making it easier to parse, but
   introducing another level of complexity and possibly slowing down
   queries, or
3. some other solution for associating a user’s email with
   each relevant piece of the DB, in order to apply Firebase Security
   Rules

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html) and [blog](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) [posts](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html) [on](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) structuring data and best practices. The docs are also under a major revamp that should include more detail about architecture. These would provide a great primer.